# Changing base namespace mapping in SOAP envelope

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Does anyone know how to change the namespace name of SOAP response to match with the one I am getting from the SOAP request?

For example if I am getting the following as SOAP request from the client side

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
       <method:Login>
          <method:userName>?</method:userName>
          <method:password>?</method:password>
       </method:Login>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

SOAP response from the server should be like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        ResponseString
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But server is returning

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      Response String
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any way I can change `xmlns:soapenv` to `xmlns:soap` dynamically in the SOAP response structure through Java class or through some other method?

Comment: You don't have to. The *prefix* is only a convenient way to represent the actual namespace URI (which in both cases is "`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`"). What is the *real* problem that you're having?

Comment: v r trying to create a replica of a web service for a mobile app but that web service is returning data inside <soap:envelope></soap:envelope>.. and my web service is returning response inside <soapenv:envelope> which is creating problem during parsing

Comment: If you're getting a problem during parsing, then show the information about the problem. I will guarantee, however, that if you're using a real parser (versus trying to do it yourself via string manipulation), the prefix is *not* the problem.

Comment: Ok I will check again